# Ruby upgrade / downgrade from 1.9.3-p194 to 1.9.3-p286

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-upgrade

I just upgraded from ruby `1.9.3-p194` to `1.9.3-p286` via the rvm upgrade command and the gemset. Now when I run rake rails upgrade on my rails app it gives me the following trace:

```
nosh@nosh-VirtualBox:~/Projects/icon$ rake rails update --trace
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- ruby_debug.so
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `require'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26/lib/ruby-debug-base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `require'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/home/nosh/Projects/icon/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nosh/Projects/icon/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/nosh/Projects/icon/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/nosh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. If its the ruby version conflict with ruby debug 19 gem. Then how should I downgrade back to `1.9.3-p194`.

Comment: If you're installing through rvm, you should be able to switch back to that patch level `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194`. Also not really an answer, but you could always try debugging with pry instead :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just had to try it; but the same rvm command that allows the upgrade also allows downgrade. So the following command allowed me to downgrade to the previous version:

```
rvm upgrade 1.9.3-p286 1.9.3-p194
```

It migrated the gems as well.
By the way I also found out after the downgrade that the rake rails update command I used had incorrect syntax.
So this is incorrect:

```
rake rails update --trace (incorrect)
```

This is correct:

```
rake rails:update --trace (correct)
```

I did not get the error after the upgrade again, that means I was probably using the wrong syntax.